# Unable to verify text with string (variable), how ever it is working fine with static text "testing"

Tags: java

Addlscm Add_lsc_Maa2=PageFactory.initElements(driver, Addlscm.class); Add_lsc_Maa2.addleadsourcecode2("Clear Connect", Randomtext.RLSCT(),Randomtext.RLSCT());

```
System.out.println(Addlscm.CLSCN);  
Thread.sleep(5000); 
String test = Addlscm.CLSCN;    

if (driver.getPageSource().contains(test))  
{   
 System.out.println("pass");
 }     
else { 
System.out.println("fail"); 
} 

System.out.println(test);
```

Unable to verify text with string variable (above code), however, working fine with below code 
Actually, I have created a unique username with random numbers/text and functional return string to main class then i isn't working for verification, I have also print save string before or after and have the same value but unable to verify on the page, can anyone help he in this case?

```
    if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Robert"))                                          
                {
                System.out.println("pass");
               }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("fail");                         
                }
    enter code here
```

Comment: Your code-snippets is in Java, so that tag makes sense. You read a web-page, so the JavaScript tag makes some kind of sense I guess (but not much since the question isn't really about it). But what about the C# tag? Why did you add that? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Java: unless you have a variable named `String` (which would be a really bad choice), the first one won't work, because the compiler thinks you are referring to the type `String`.

Comment: We need to see more code to help. The first version works if you have a `String` variable called `String`.

Comment: You should to describe variable regarding your idea: 
String str = 'dsfa';
if (driver.getPageSource().contains(str))                                         
            {
            System.out.println("pass");
           }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("fail");                         
            }

Answer (score 1):

Change variable name `String` to something else.

```
String cont = "testing";
if(driver.getPageSource().contains(cont)){
 System.out.println("pass");
}else{
 System.out.println("fail");
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, i have already done that but it can't work,

Comment: @JohnRobert plz, provide more code, where u define that variable.

Comment: Actually, i have created a unique username with random numbers/text and functional return string to main class then i isn't working,  I have also print save string before or after and have the same value but unable to verify on the page, can anyone help he in this case?

Comment: Addlscm Add_lsc_Maa2=PageFactory.initElements(driver, Addlscm.class);
   Add_lsc_Maa2.addleadsourcecode2("Clear Connect", Randomtext.RLSCT(), Randomtext.RLSCT());
   
   System.out.println(Addlscm.CLSCN); 
 
   Thread.sleep(5000); 
   String test = Addlscm.CLSCN;  
   
   if (driver.getPageSource().contains(test))          
     
       {    
       System.out.println("pass");
      }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("fail");  
     
    }

   System.out.println(test);